# Localised AngularJS Routes

Tags: javascript, angularjs, backbone.js, angular-routing

I have been coding BackboneJS and have successfully built large projects using BackboneJS and AMD.

I am now looking into using AngularJS and have got an implementation with AMD and have built some controllers and services so pretty comfortable so far.

Only thing is that we build a lot of applications that need to be localised for different territories. Because of this I have successfully configured Angular Translate and it works fine.

What Angular Translate does not support is the creation of localised url routing which is something I was able to achieve easily in BackboneJS by dynamically updating the routes object.

Can anyone point me in the right direction for an article or post on how to do this with AngularJS. Been trawling through Google but cannot seem to find anything!

Comment: Do you localise at run time or do you build localised apps and deploy them separately?

Comment: I localise at run time by retrieving the urls and url formats from an external file. This is so localised translations can be made in an xml/json file by users in my office with a recognised format. Currently I have a service that retrieves the json translation contents and then I have tried to set these routes dynamically in the $route.routes object in my controller but the urls are not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, whether or not this is the best solution for you I'll explain an approach we took when it came to having a *dumb* Angular app that required routes be defined on the backend. So at run time the URL that the user comes in on is unknown to our app, what we do is the following:

- Call a service that defines our app URLs
- Validate the retrieved URLs
- Call `$route.reload()` to essentially *restart* (it doesn't actually restart the application, but just runs the route parser again) the application

We then defined routes based on the app's features, eg: `http://foo.bar/product/:slug`. So if a user came in on `http://foo.bar/product/foobar` the app at run time has no idea whether or not `foobar` exists. This allowed us to keep the UI dumb and define the routes on the backend; therefore...

1. In your routes config set up base routes, eg `/product/:slug`, `/page/:slug`, etc...
2. Create a factory that keeps a boolean variable which is whether or not the app has loaded the localisation data; if it's false then your `product`, `page`, etc... controllers will just silently stop at their `init`
3. In your base controller load your localisation data, validate it, etc... Once you're happy you then run `$route.reload()` and this time set the factory flag to true
4. Your `product`, `page`, etc... controllers will get called again, but the factory flag will be true, then they can now refer to your loaded localisation data
5. Profit

Hopefully it doesn't sound painful, it *can* be an elegant solution and works really well. Just make sure you have a nice polite loader.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Ahmed. In terms of setting up the routes when I get the content back from the server I am currently calling $route.routes['/' + route.url] = {controller: "MainController", templateUrl: 'views/' + route.template}; with the url and templateUrl being values passed back from the server. Is this correct?

Comment: Sorry about the late response. So the idea is to have abstract routes for each of your pieces of content, eg `/product/:productSlug` would point to your `product-controller-partial.html`, then in your `ProductController` you take the `$routeParams.productSlug`, check it against your loaded content and then work out whether this item exists or not. What we did is made use of the `.resolve()` that allowed us to check multiple routes with the same concept, eg takes a base and id and checks against API or loaded config.

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. Still finding my feet a bit with Angular but will have a look at this and see if I can get something working!

Comment: Thanks for this Ahmed, one step closer although the word 'product' for example can be 'produkt' in German and 'producto' in spanish so because I have to set that top level page to map it to a template url then am I right in thinking I cannot localise the first part of the url?

Comment: Well, it all depends on how you do it. Product doesn't have to be a word, it could just be P or 1, for example, you could do /p/:id/:product/:slug, so /p/123/producto/chorizo

Comment: Thanks Ahmed. Are you saying that if you want to serve a page for a specific locale then the top level route has to be hard coded into Angular's config?

Comment: Yep, so the route in the example I posted is /p/, which then allows you to localise the properties.

Comment: Thanks for all your help Ahmed. I have logged an issue on Angular's Github page as I consider being able to localise the top level routes quite an important part of how our applications should run. An example of us using that is http://www.tbbtsuperfan.com/superfan-leaders. If I wanted to do the same thing for Germany then I would want to do http://de.tbbtsuperfan.com/superfan-spizengruppe without having to run a separate application.